# Need help to create new notepad++ file with selected xml tag's data

Tags: notepad++

I am new to Notepad++ and need help to copy selected fields into a new file, so that I can use that to further process those fields in Excel .
I have a huge XML file and need only 6 or 7 fields from each row,
Shift+Alt copies all fields values when all rows have this XML tag aligned to same position , but unfortunately my file here is of Varied length, hence couldn't use Shift+Alt.

[Original XML file]

```
<documents xmlns:xsi=.......>
<document><Name>aaaa</Name>..<ContactNo>11111</ContactNo>.....<Zip>10101</Zip>.........</document>
<document><Name>bbbb</Name>...........<ContactNo>22222</ContactNo>..<Zip>12121</Zip>...</document>
<document><Name>cccc</Name>...<ContactNo>33333</ContactNo>..<Zip>13131</Zip>...........</document>
<document><Name>dddd</Name>..........<ContactNo>44444</ContactNo>.....<Zip>14141</Zip>.</document>
.
.
.
</documents>
```

[Desired Target file]

```
<aaaa<11111<54321 
<bbbb<22222<22221 
<cccc<33333<33331
<dddd<44444<14141
.
.
.
```

Comment: Pressing "Shift+Alt" does not do anything, they are modifiers and only make sense when used with other keys.

Comment: Use an XML parser.